# subsetting an R data.table delimited by empty rows

Tags: r, data.table, subset, data-cleaning

I am trying to extract and clean data from excel files using R. Some of these excel files contain multiple table structures (separated by empty rows) that I would like to separate into multiple data.tables.

I'm simply trying to return the indices of the rows that are completely empty using:

```
blankrows <- which(all(is.na(tempdata)), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

which I could then use to subset the data ("tempdata" is a data.table)

If I just use `is.na(tempdata)`, I get all indices that have any NA values (which is not what I want), but when I use `all()`, I don't get any even though there are definitely empty rows. I am probably misunderstanding either or both of these functions, but the way I understand it is that `is.na()` returns a vector of logical variables and that `all()` should return true if they are all true.

Comment: I you wrap it with `all`, iit would be a single `TRUE/FALSE` and then wrapping with `which` returns either 1.  It would be easier to check the NAs by row,  and then do that to split the dataset.  i.e. `i1 <- dt[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, is.na))] ; split(dt,  cumsum(i1))`

Comment: BTW, the `|` or `&` have backquotes around it.  It is just not clear which way you want tto split i.e. if the whole row is NA or any NA row

Comment: maybe check out `readxl` package as it allows one to read rectangular blocks on data within Excel?

Comment: Thanks so much, @akrun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a logical index with `is.na` and `Reduce`, convert it to numeric by doing the cumulative sum and `split` the data into a `list` of datasets

```
i1 <- dt[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, is.na))] 
split(dt, cumsum(i1))
```